# Android/Kotlin: Edit Text email result become asterisk ( **** )

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-edittext

I use device Vivo 1819.

I'm confused, why the return from EditText, when I `println, Log, and JSON except use Toast` result comes out as asterisks ( `****` ).

I try with EditText and the Button returns the value `*****`

`MainActivity.kt`

```java
package com.sentul.otopark.activity

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.sentul.otopark.R
import com.sentul.otopark.utils.URL_CHECK_EMAIL

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val etRegisterMail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.txtUsername)
        val mbRegister = findViewById<Button>(R.id.mbRegister)

        mbRegister.setOnClickListener {
            val etRegisterMailParam = etRegisterMail.text.toString()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Email input is $etRegisterMailParam", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Url input is $URL_CHECK_EMAIL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            println("Email is ${getText(etRegisterMail)}")
            println("URL is $URL_CHECK_EMAIL")
        }
    }

    private fun getText(editText: EditText): String {
        return editText.text.toString()
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mbRegister"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fontFamily="@font/fira_sans_extra_bold_italic"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:textColor="@color/white_ffffff"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Image result try with EditText + Button]

And I try with TextWatcher but got a return value of `*****`

`RegisterActivity.kt`

```java
package com.sentul.otopark.activity

import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.sentul.otopark.R
import com.sentul.otopark.databinding.ActivityRegisterBinding
import com.sentul.otopark.dialog.LoadingFullScreenDialog
import com.sentul.otopark.utils.SystemUtil
import com.sentul.otopark.utils.SystemUtil.Companion.goneView
import com.sentul.otopark.utils.SystemUtil.Companion.handleDisable
import com.sentul.otopark.utils.SystemUtil.Companion.handleEventClick
import com.sentul.otopark.utils.SystemUtil.Companion.visibleView
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject

class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var binding: ActivityRegisterBinding? = null
    private var progressBar: LoadingFullScreenDialog? = null

    private var tagClassName = "RegisterActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityRegisterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding!!.root)

        progressBar = LoadingFullScreenDialog()

        binding!!.llLogin.setOnClickListener {
            it.handleEventClick(3)
            finish()
        }

        binding!!.mbRegister.setOnClickListener {
            it.handleEventClick(3)
            progressBar!!.show(this, getString(R.string.please_wait))
            val paramJsonObject = JSONObject()
            try {
                paramJsonObject.put("email", binding!!.etEmail.text)
                Log.i(tagClassName, "Parameter JSON is $paramJsonObject")
                dismissProgressDialog()
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                Log.e(tagClassName, "Error generate JSON is ${e.printStackTrace()}")
                dismissProgressDialog()
            }
        }

        initUI()
        initEvent()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        binding = null
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        finish()
    }

    private fun initUI() {
        binding!!.mbRegister.handleDisable(false)

        binding!!.etEmail.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(text: Editable?) {
                checkValidation(text.toString())
                Log.i(tagClassName, "afterTextChanged $text")
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
        })
    }

    private fun initEvent() {

    }

    private fun checkValidation(text: String) {
        val isEmail = if (SystemUtil.isValidEmail(text)) {
            binding!!.tvErrorEmail.goneView()
            Log.i(tagClassName, "checkValidation $text")
            true
        } else {
            binding!!.tvErrorEmail.visibleView()
            false
        }
        binding!!.mbRegister.handleDisable(!(isEmail))
    }

    private fun dismissProgressDialog() {
        if (progressBar!!.getDialog() != null) {
            progressBar!!.getDialog()!!.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

`activity_register.xml`

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white_ffffff"
    tools:context=".activity.RegisterActivity">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nsvRegister"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mbRegister"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="179dp"
                android:layout_height="116dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="127dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/fira_sans_extra_bold_italic"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/register"
                android:textColor="@color/black_252525"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/enter_your_email_address_to_register"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_505050"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|start"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:text="@string/email"
                android:textColor="@color/black_252525"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_text_field_ecf2f7"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="@string/youremail_gmail_com"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:importantForAutofill="no"
                    android:inputType="textEmailSubject"
                    android:paddingStart="12dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="12dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivErrorEmail"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_danger"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvErrorEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|start"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:text="@string/invalid_email_try_another_email"
                android:textColor="@color/error"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llLogin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
                    android:gravity="center|end"
                    android:text="@string/already_have_an_account_question_mark"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_505050"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_regular"
                    android:gravity="center|start"
                    android:text="@string/login"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mbRegister"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:fontFamily="@font/fira_sans_extra_bold_italic"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:textColor="@color/white_ffffff"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Image result try with TextWatcher]

Comment: What is your question? [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RickyMo I use device vivo 1819 I'm confused, why the return from EditText, when i 'println, Log, and JSON except use Toast' result become asterisk ( **** )

Comment: Muhamad's asking why the ``EditText``'s ``text`` value is becoming asterisks - from the last screenshot (with the ``TextWatcher``) it looks like it happens when the length exceeds 9 characters. Does it happen in an emulator?

Comment: @cactustictacs in emulator nothing happened

Comment: Does it actually turn into asterisks on the screen, or can you see the full email address? If it does turn into asterisks, when you delete a few characters, does it show the text again, or does it stay as asterisks? Does removing the ``inputType`` attributes in the XML change anything? This is really weird behaviour, and if you're not seeing it in the emulator, your device is doing something strange (maybe some changes the company made to Android). You might just need to find a workaround that avoids it happening

Comment: 1. Does it actually turn into asterisks on the screen, or can you see the full email address? I can only see when the toast appears, if in front of the '@' character the email is deleted to '@gmail.com' but if the deletion is in front of '.com' it has to be '.c 'and then ' a@gmail.c ' appears

Comment: @cactustictacs 
2. If it does turn into asterisks, when you delete a few characters, does it show the text again, or does it stay as asterisks? Yes, stay as asterisks

Comment: @cactustictacs 3. Does removing the inputType attributes in the XML change anything? No

Comment: I'm talking about your ``EditText``, the thing you're typing an address into. According to your ``TextWatcher`` output, the contents of that EditText start normal but then turn into asterisks after you enter 9(?) characters - I'm asking if you see that on the screen while you're entering the email address, if it all turns into asterisks. It would be strange if you don't see them in the UI, but ``yourEditText.text.toString()`` returns something completely different. I don't have a solution to this by the way, I have no idea what's happening, just trying to get more info in case someone can help